# Toggle list items after button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i managed to get my buttons to show the list items in the unordered list. But now every time i click a button all the list items nested in unordered list appears and disappears when the button is clicked again.

This is my updated HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-black" id="services">
<div class="services">
<h2>SERVICES</h2>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 iconpad-even">
  <img src="img/icons/icon_data_edit.png" alt="data"/>
  <button class="icon-btn" data-button="btnData">DATA</button>
  <ul class="showData">
    <li>Design</li>
    <li>Cable Installation</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>CAT5e, CAT6, CAT6A</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 iconpad-odd">
  <img src="img/icons/fiber-icon-edit.png" alt="fiber-icon" />
  <button class="icon-btn" data-button="btnFiber">FIBER</button>
  <ul class="showData">
    <li>Consultancy</li>
    <li>Building to Building</li>
    <li>Network Backbone</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Basically i have 6 div's that are structured the exact same way, only difference is the content on the list items.

I've removed the display:none on the services ul li and added it to the css .showData class as suggested by @Mohammed-Yusef

Here's the current jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$('.icon-btn').on('click', function() {
$('.showData').toggle();    
});
});
```

Comment: Check my answer below and its working as expected and have explained the issue you have with couple of selectors and click event syntax.

Comment: @Aruna i've tried the new function of: $(this).next('.showData li').toggle() but now it seems now that the button doesn't expand the list items anymore. All i did was put the same button class on 4 more ul items. Please advise

Comment: Can you update the htm for this here so that it will be easy to provide you the answer ?

Comment: @Aruna I actually was able to trigger the button to show the list items, but now the problem is that the button is triggering the list items for all the divs. Also, do i just edit the original code to show you what is happening?

Comment: Yes please edit the original code

Comment: Hi @Aruna did you get a chance to check the edited code?

Comment: I have updated my answer below with `$(this).next('.showData').find('li').toggle()` which is working now as you expected. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks again! @Aruna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery syntax of the click function should be as given below and also in your css you are hiding all the `li` elements. So you have to toggle them back with the selector `$('.showData li')` instead of `$('.showData')`. Also use `.icon-btn` instead of `.icon-button` as you don't have such a class mentioned in your html.

```
$('.icon-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.showData li').toggle();    
 });
```

Working snippet,

```js
$(function() {
 $('.icon-btn').on('click', function() {
    //$('.showData li').toggle();  
    $(this).next('.showData').find('li').toggle();
 });
});
```

```css
.services ul li {
display: none;
margin-left: -1.8em; 
/*color: #fff;*/
list-style: none;
margin-bottom: 1em;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Oswald', 'open-sans';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-center bg-black" id="services">
<div class="services">
<h2>SERVICES</h2>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 iconpad-even">
  <img src="img/icons/icon_data_edit.png" alt="data"/>
  <button class="icon-btn" data-button="btnData">DATA</button>
  <ul class="showData">
    <li>Design</li>
    <li>Cable Installation</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    <li>CAT5e, CAT6, CAT6A</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 iconpad-odd">
  <img src="img/icons/fiber-icon-edit.png" alt="fiber-icon" />
  <button class="icon-btn" data-button="btnFiber">FIBER</button>
  <ul class="showData">
    <li>Consultancy</li>
    <li>Building to Building</li>
    <li>Network Backbone</li>
    <li>Testing</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how would i go about adding jquery code if i had multiple buttons and each button has it's own list items?

Comment: May I know how do you identify which button should hide which list items, do you have any identifier, lets say any index etc?

Comment: Accepted no :( .. then +1 from me cause you catch the css problem first  no:(  .. and I think he needs `$(this).next('.showData li').toggle();` instead of `$('.showData li').toggle();`  .. Have a great day Aruna :-)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thanks mate and you too have a great day.

Comment: @NoahMistry You can try `$(this).next('.showData li').toggle()` if the list items are next element of each buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have an element with a class `icon-button` your button has a class `icon-btn` so use `$('.icon-btn')` instead of  `$('.icon-button')`

and you can use

```
$(function() {
 $('.icon-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.showData').toggle();    
 });
});
```

and in css use

```
.showData{
   display: none;
}
```

and remove `display:none` from `.services ul li`

> **Note:** be sure to include jquery

Comment: Why are you asking to change the css as it can be handled from the jquery click event  as given in my answer though you haven't picked up this before I answered, LOL :-) ?

Comment: @Aruna Actually I didn't realize the css point until you post your answer .. then I said to myself wT** how I missed that point :-)  .. Ok to be fair if I got the accept answer I will upvote yours :-) fair enough :-))

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".icon-button", function(){
    $('.showData').toggle();    
});
```