# Is there a way to prevent slideToggle on every element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with slideToggle function with jQuery. When I click on the div everything is working just fine I mean the toggle. But I have a problem that when I click on the div one div every element moves. Is there a way how to move only the div that I clicked ???

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
      $("#test").slideToggle("slow");
    })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4">
              <img src="assets/kids-2580991_1920.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="https://www.vavaland.sk/">
                <div class="bottom-left" id="toggle">Pohybová príprava JUNIOR a TEEN</div>
                <div id="test" style="display: none;padding:50px;">testjandkansdlkjnaskjdnkajsdnjkasndkjansdkjanjkasd</div>
            </div>
```

EDIT : See the gif for more understanding

https://giphy.com/gifs/dBOZRXfUNm2pkmuRGa

Comment: Do you have non-unique IDs on your document, e.g. using `#toggle` and/or `#test` for multiple elements? If so, that is your problem. Use classes instead and `this` inside the click handler to reference to the clicked element

Comment: still not working all the next three elements moving with the first one

Comment: Maybe this answer may be useful for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44016288/3933878